# Semaphore Program results in Deadlock

Tags: deadlock, semaphore

I was told to write a program to make two processes which will synchronize with each other to print '00110011...'

I have the following code:

```
#include"headers.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    sem_t smid;
    if(sem_init(&smid, 1, 1)<0){
        perror("sem_init");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        //child process
        while(1){   
            if(sem_wait(&smid)<0){
                perror("sem_wait");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("00");
            sleep(1);
            if(sem_post(&smid)<0){
                perror("sem post");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

        }
    }else{
        while(1){
            if(sem_wait(&smid)<0){
                perror("sem_wait");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("11");
            sleep(1);
            if(sem_post(&smid)<0){
                perror("sem post");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

header.s:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#include<semaphore.h>
#include<unistd.h>
```

The above code results in a deadlock and I can't understand why.
P.S. I have noticed that the deadlock is removed when I remove **both the sleep()** function calls.

I need to understand where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A couple notes: 1) There is a race here, because both processes will try to `sem_wait` at the same time and one of them will succeed. Which process will succeed? Who knows! 2) You will want to `fflush(stdout);` after `printf()`.

Comment: Wow! The ```fflush(stdout)``` worked! But I have no idea why. Can you please explain? (You can post it as an answer). Also, can you please provide tips to avoid the race condition?

Comment: As it turns out, it wasn't a deadlock after all.

Comment: The `fflush(stdout)` is because stdout is line-buffered. Because you're not writing a full line with an \n at the end, printf just writes to the buffer, and fflush is necessary to write the buffer to the console. To fix the race condition you'll need two semaphores.

Comment: Okay. But if that's the only reason, why do I get an output when the ```sleep(1);``` statement is removed from both the processes?

Comment: Without sleep, the output will quickly fill up the buffer and it will flush when that happens. With sleep, the buffer will still fill up and automatically flush, but it will take many seconds.

Comment: Oh. Thanks so much for the explanation. Helped a lot.